# Heroku and Django connection pool

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Django does not have any connection pooling. Instead, they recommend working with an external pool, like pgBouncer.
This worked great for me in the past, but I am wondering how can get pgbouncer (or something similar) in Heroku (Heroku App <-> Heroku hosted postgres DB).
This is crucial since the 150ms connection time per request is not acceptable.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using [django-db-pool](https://github.com/gmcguire/django-db-pool) its a connection pooling DB driver for django that works pretty well. We have many users using this on Heroku who are pretty happy with it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have seen it and wanted to use. However, it explicitly requires Django 1.3, while I am using 1.4.1 . I have left an issue in the repo, requesting an upgrade to 1.4 if possible.